# Reduce docker image size with Python and R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, docker

Hi have created dockerfile(multi-stage) for python and R. But the size was nearly 1.95GB. Initially it was 2.45GB, after using multi-stage it is reduces to 1.95GB. But still I'm looking for optimization.When I checked, the python/site-package size was nearly 985MB.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim-2021-06-09 As stage1

COPY key_gnupg.gpg /app/key_gnupg.gpg
RUN echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until \"false\";\nAcquire::Check-Date \"false\";" | cat > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10no--check-valid-until
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    echo "deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list && \
    apt-key add /app/key_gnupg.gpg && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y pkg-config liblapack-dev gfortran libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libnlopt-dev r-base curl postgresql libpq-dev libblas-dev libpcre2-8-0 libgomp1 build-essential && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get purge --auto-remove && \
    apt-get clean

FROM stage1 AS stage2
COPY ./ /app
COPY requirements*.txt ./    
COPY r-scripts /app/r-scripts
WORKDIR /app/r-scripts
RUN R -e " install.packages('remotes')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_local('.', dependencies=T, Ncpus=3)"
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pip install -U pip && \ 
    pip install --no-cache-dir  --user -r requirements-frozen-prod.txt

FROM stage1
COPY --from=stage2 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
COPY --from=stage2 /root/.local /root/.local
COPY --from=stage2 /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
WORKDIR /app/
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
ENV PATH=/root/.local/bin:$PATH
ENV R_HOME="/usr/lib/R"
RUN rm -rf /app/*
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

python requirement.txt

```
alembic==1.7.1
anyio==3.3.0
astroid==2.7.3
attrs==21.2.0
autoflake==1.4
autopep8==1.5.7
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
black==21.8b0
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.14.6
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
click==7.1.2
coverage==5.5
dependency-check==0.6.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
fastapi==0.65.2
flake8==3.9.2
flake8-formatter-junit-xml==0.0.6
future==0.18.2
google-api-core==2.0.1
google-auth==2.0.2
google-cloud-bigquery==2.26.0
google-cloud-core==2.0.0
google-crc32c==1.2.0
google-resumable-media==2.0.3
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
grpcio==1.39.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h11==0.11.0
httpcore==0.13.6
httptools==0.1.1
httpx==0.19.0
idna==3.2
importlib-resources==5.2.2
iniconfig==1.1.1
isort==5.9.3
Jinja2==3.0.1
junit-xml==1.8
kaleido==0.2.1
lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0
Mako==1.1.5
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
mccabe==0.6.1
mypy==0.910
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
numpy==1.21.2
openpyxl==3.0.7
openpyxl-image-loader==1.0.5
packaging==21.0
pandas==1.3.2
pathspec==0.9.0
patsy==0.5.1
Pillow==8.3.2
platformdirs==2.3.0
plotly==5.3.1
pluggy==1.0.0
proto-plus==1.19.0
protobuf==3.17.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
py==1.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pybigquery==0.10.2
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pycparser==2.20
pydantic==1.8.2
pyflakes==2.3.1
pylint==2.10.2
pylint-junit==0.3.2
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-asyncio==0.15.1
pytest-cov==2.12.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.15.0
pytz==2021.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2021.8.28
requests==2.26.0
rfc3986==1.5.0
rpy2==3.4.5
rsa==4.7.2
scipy==1.7.1
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24
starlette==0.14.2
statsmodels==0.12.2
tenacity==8.0.1
toml==0.10.2
tomli==1.2.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
tzlocal==3.0
urllib3==1.26.6
uvicorn==0.13.1
uvloop==0.14.0
watchgod==0.6
websockets==8.1
wrapt==1.12.1
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==3.0.1
zipp==3.5.0
```

Comment: On one hand, I'm not surprised, since a full R and Python environment will not be small. And this may simply be the case. On the other hand, we don't know which Python packages you're installing, for example.

Comment: How large is your base installation, that is, without R and Python installed (So with all the libraries installed)?

Comment: the base installation was 893MB

Comment: Updated question with python list of packages

Comment: For fun, I installed the list of Python packages myself to see. `kaleido` takes up about 221Mb of disk space; `plotly` about 140Mb, `scipy` about 68Mb, `pandas` about 57MB, and downwards from there. (I am mostly surprised by `pydantic` taking up 45Mb of disk space; it looks like it has a whole bunch of dynamic libraries due to the way it hacks(?) into Python.)

Comment: So, depending whether you really need a package, this are the ones to go after initially.

Comment: I was curious about Kaleido (never heard of it): it brings a 184Mb executable, `kaleido`, with it, in `lib/python3.9/site-packages/kaleido/executable/bin`. The reason seems to be (quoted from the Kaleido page): "The core of Kaleido is a standalone C++ application that embeds the open-source Chromium browser as a library." So you just installed a browser when you installed Kaleido.

Comment: apart from python package, is there way to reduce the docker image size

Answer (score 0):

This [technique](https://blog.mapbox.com/aws-lambda-python-magic-e0f6a407ffc6) is used in the context of reducing the size of AWS lambda functions but also applies to Docker images.

The idea is to remove all the .py files under site-packages and use the .pyc files only since these libraries will not (I'm assuming) be changed.

Note that for same cases the .py may still be required but that seems to be rare.